# Validation error Form Request v-model Laravel vue.js

Tags: php, laravel, validation, vue.js, laravel-5.3

I have a problem.

I'm using a Form Request but also Vue on my form. My problem is that `old('')` variables does not work together with Vue `v-model`.

Here is an example of the input field.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">{{ trans('messages.name') }}</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" v-model="name" id="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" class="form-control">
    @if($errors->has('name'))
      <span class="help">
        {{trans('Validations.name')}}
      </span>
    @endif
</div>
```

If I remove the v-model="name" the {{ old('name') }} variable works.

This is the error i get from Vue in the browser.

> ```
> <input v-model="name" value="asdasdasd">:
> ```
>
> inline value attributes will be ignored when using v-model. Declare initial values in the component's data option instead.

**vue file**

```
<script>
  import RangeSlider from './RangeSlider.vue';

  export default {
    components: {
      RangeSlider,
    },

    props: ['fields'],

    data() {
      return {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        loading: false,
        errors: {},
      };
    },

    methods: {
      onSubmit() {
        this.loading = true;
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`Vue` does not allow you to initialise model data from the `HTML`, because `Vue` expects you to retrieve data from an `API` and set it from  the `Vue instance`, which can be a pain when using it in conjunction with `blade`. The simplest way around this is to create a directive to make the `init` yourself:

```
Vue.directive('init', {
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    vnode.context[binding.arg] = binding.value;
  }
})
```

Then use as:

```
<input type="text" name="name" v-model="name" id="name" v-init:name="'{{old('name')}}'" class="form-control">
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0uvqmodc/

Comment: Something in addition(since OP seems new to vue): `v-model` binds user input with the `name` in `data`, so it needs to obey the initial value in the script, and can't at the same time obey the `value` in the template(which is also a *initial value*), thus the error. To get around this, the first idea is to set `old()` in js, with some global vars. This answer cleverly allow us to pass data from the server in the template, and use a directive who modifies the script `data` to avoid the multi-initial-value problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this with the help of [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind), which dynamically bind one or more attributes.

```
<input type="text" name="name" v-model="name" id="name" v-bind:value="old('name')" class="form-control">
```

However if you want to set an initial value to the input field, you can just set the data variable `name` as the value (`old('name')`) you want to set.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="name" v-model="name" id="name" class="form-control">
```

**JS**

```
data() {
  return {
    name: 'oldValue',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    loading: false,
    errors: {},
  };
},
```

Comment: using v-bind:value failed to compile template. Any ideas?

Comment: @EdvardÅkerberg I dont see any error [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j1ecyryf/)